# set combobox text from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have user submitted content that is loaded into c# winform in our office for processing before officially added to database. The user can submit a 'Referrer' as two text fields-first and last name. In the office I want to have a combobox will all existing referrers loaded in, then the first couple letters of the name to advance the combobox down to the area it needs to be at. I want to do something like this, taking the first two letters of the name and use that to initialize the combobox.

```
if (txtrefFirstName.TextLength > 2)
{
   string firstStart = "" + txtrefFirstName.Text[0] + txtrefFirstName.Text[1];
   firstStart = firstStart.ToUpper();
   ddlReferring.SelectedText.StartsWith(firstStart);
}
else
   ddlReferring.Text = "";
```

Any ideas or suggestions to get this to work?

Thanks

David K.

Comment: Are you typing the names directly in the combobox, or in a separate TextBox control?

Comment: You have to do a foreach loop on ddlReferring and then check if item StartsWith(firstStart) then select it.

Comment: Wasn't get a syntax error, it just wasn't working right.  The combobox can autocomplete, but I wanted to advance to list to close to what it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write something like this...

```
foreach (string item in ddlReferring.Items)
{
    if (item.StartsWith(firstStart))
    {
        ddlReferring.SelectedText = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This got me in the right direction, with a slight change, posted in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ddl's datasource is a List of String objects, you should be able to do some comparison on the datasource itself.  I tend to use Linq for things like this but it isn't strictly necessary, just shorter.

```
if (txtrefFirstName.TextLength > 2)
{
   string firstStart = txtrefFirstName.Text.Substring(0,2).ToUpper();
   string Selection = ddlReferring.DataSource.Where(a=>a.StartsWith(firstStart)).FirstOrDefault();
   ddlReferring.SelectedText = Selection ?? "";
}
else
   ddlReferring.Text = "";
```

The selection line can also come from the items collection directly

```
string Selection = ddlReferring.Items.OfType<string>().Where(a=>a.StartsWith(firstStart)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if you REALLY dont want to use Linq...

```
string Selection = "";
foreach (object item in ddlReferring.Items)
    if (item.ToString().StartsWith(firstStart))
    {
        Selection = item.ToString();
        break;
    }
```

Similar methods can be used even if the ddl's data is not a list of strings, just make sure to cast the items appropriately and compare the correct values.